# keras/tensorflow/unable to set parameter class_weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

everyone. I`m trying train U-Net model on binary images and I have imbalanced data set. I have two classes [0,1] and use binary_crossentropy:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 1e-5),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My model.summary() as follows:

```
    Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 256, 256, 64) 640         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 256, 256, 64) 256         conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 256, 256, 64) 256         conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 73856       max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 128 512         conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 128 512         conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 256)  1024        conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 256)  1024        conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 512)  2048        conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 512)  2359808     batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 512)  2048        conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 512)  0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 1024) 4719616     max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 1024) 4096        conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 1024) 9438208     batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 1024) 4096        conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D)    (None, 32, 32, 1024) 0           batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  2097664     up_sampling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 32, 32, 1024) 0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
                                                                 conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  4719104     concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 512)  2048        conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 512)  2359808     batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 512)  2048        conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  524544      up_sampling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 512)  0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
                                                                 conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  1179904     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 256)  1024        conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  590080      batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 256)  1024        conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 256 0           batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 131200      up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 256 0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
                                                                 conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 295040      concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 128 512         conv2d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 147584      batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 128 512         conv2d_18[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 256, 256, 128 0           batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 32832       up_sampling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 256, 128 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
                                                                 conv2d_19[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 73792       concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 64) 256         conv2d_20[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 64) 256         conv2d_21[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 2)  130         batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,054,210
Trainable params: 31,042,434
Non-trainable params: 11,776
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

I`m trying set class_weights parametr as follow:

```
class_weights = {0:1,1:63.2}
model.fit_generator(trainGen,epochs=25, steps_per_epoch=(firstNumFile + lastNumFile)/batchSize, callbacks=[early_stopping,model_checkpoint,tensor_board],
                   validation_data=validGen,validation_steps=(firtTestFile + lastTestFile)/batchSize,shuffle=True,class_weight=class_weights)
```

but I get error message:

```
ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.
```

I use keras 2.43 version and tf 2.4.1 version. I suspect I'm getting this error because of the two channels in the output layer. Is there a way to specify weights for classes in my case?

Comment: if I remember well for doing such classification you need to bring the conv layer to a perceptron at minimum, and use an activation function according to the problem; this case appears to be binary since i read two clases in the class_weights dictionary.

that's why you get "ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.".

for example, connect the last conv to a dense(1) with sigmoid, or dense(2) with softmax activaction function. that scheme should do.

Comment: add also a flatten layer in between. hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 target classes, due to which it isnt specifying more than 3 dimensional targets. Your class weights should be changed {0:1,1:2.}

Comment: you wrote the same "{0:1,1:2.}"